# (SFML, C++) How to access specific sf::Vertex in dynamically allocated sf::VertexArray?

Tags: c++, sfml

I am new to SFML, learning it in C++ and I have this problem which I can't solve.
What my program (class) contains is:

in header file:

```cpp
sf::VertexArray *hitbox;
```

in source file:

```cpp
this->hitbox = new sf::VertexArray(sf::TriangleFan, 20); //example
```

and there's a method

```cpp
void Object::setPosition(sf::Vector2f position)
{
    if(this->hitbox->getVertexCount()!=0)
    {
        this->hitbox->position = position; //error here
    }
}
```

Compiler says this:

```
 error: 'class sf::VertexArray' has no member named 'position'
   this->hitbox->position = position;
                 ^
```

So the problem is that I want to change the position of the first vertex, but it seems that I can't access it when I alloc `sf::VertexArray` dynamically. I've read on https://www.sfml-dev.org/ that `sf::VertexArray` is in fact `std::vector<sf::Vertex>` with [] operator overload, so there *should* be a way to do this, but I struggle to find it. Additionally, the class does not inherit from `sf::Transformable`. How can I solve this issue?

Edit:
`this->hitbox[0]->position = position;`
or
`this->hitbox[0].position = position;`
don't solve this issue. In first case compiler has problem with hitbox[0] not being a pointer, in second case it's the same error as stated above/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `this->hitbox` is a pointer to a `sf::VertexArray`, you need to dereference it before using the `operator[]`:

```
(*(this->hitbox))[0].position = position;
```

It would probably be better to not use a pointer here at all.

Comment: It worked. I thought it would be an SFML specific issue, but it turned out to be a wrong c++ syntax. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the overloaded `[]` operator as such:

`this->hitbox[0].position = position;`

This will index the 0th entry of the vertices, of which you will be able to modify as desired.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work. Compiler says this: 
 error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'sf::VertexArray'
   this->hitbox[0]->position = position;

Comment: Edited, use a period instead of an arrow.

Comment: This way we get the same result as this->hitbox->position = position. Compiler throws error presented in the post